# Who is Lucifer in Isaiah 14:11-14?

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

As the context isn't clear
and I don't speak hebrew

So I don't know what it's exactly about.

Answer (score 4):

Look back to 14:4:

> וְנָשָׂאתָ הַמָּשָׁל הַזֶּה, עַל-מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל--וְאָמָרְתָּ:  אֵיךְ שָׁבַת נֹגֵשׂ
>
> **Proclaim this allegory concerning the King of Babylon**: how the oppressor has stopped!

So the next few verses are all metaphors for the King of Babylon (a flesh-and-blood person). There's a consistent pattern of "you were so mighty, but not anymore", in various metaphorical terms.

14:14 thus reads:

> אֵיךְ נָפַלְתָּ מִשָּׁמַיִם, הֵילֵל בֶּן-שָׁחַר; נִגְדַּעְתָּ לָאָרֶץ, חוֹלֵשׁ עַל-גּוֹיִם.
>
> How did you fall from the skies, *helel ben shachar*; you were cut down to earth, weakener of nations [or "decider of nations' fates"].

*Shachar* is Hebrew for "dawn." *Helel* is "bringer"; the common translation is "the morning star" [i.e. bringer of dawn]. Another allegory for Babylon's fallen might -- you were the morning star and now you've fallen.

The [Hebrew Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%93) notes that the Greek translation was *heosphoros*, which just means "bringer of light"; that went to the Vulgate (i.e. Latin translation) "Lucifer", meaning simply "light-bearer." Later Christian interpretations took that to mean the devil, which is probably what you'd heard.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what translation you are using and where you see Lucifer. [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15945#lt=primary) translates

> Your pride has been lowered into Gehinnom, the stirring of your
>   psalteries. Maggots are spread under you, and worms cover you. How
>   have you fallen from heaven, the morning star? You have been cut down
>   to earth, You who cast lots on nations. And you said to yourself, 'To
>   the heavens will I ascend, above God's stars will I raise my throne,
>   and I will sit on the mount of the assembly, in the farthest end of
>   the north. I will ascend above the heights of the clouds; I will liken
>   myself to the Most High.'

while [Koren](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.14.11-14?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=en) translates

> Thy pomp is brought down to She᾽ol, and the noise of thy lutes: worms
>   are spread under thee, and worms cover thee. How art thou fallen from
>   heaven, O bright star, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to
>   the ground, that didst rule over the nations! For thou hast said in
>   thy heart, I will ascend into heaven, I will exalt my throne above the
>   stars of God: I will sit also upon the mount of the congregation, in
>   the farthest north: I will ascend above the heights of the clouds; I
>   will be like the most High.

and [JPS](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.14.11-14?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

> Your pomp is brought down to Sheol, And the strains of your lutes!
>   Worms are to be your bed, Maggots your blanket!” How are you fallen
>   from heaven, O Shining One, son of Dawn! How are you felled to earth,
>   O vanquisher of nations! Once you thought in your heart, “I will climb
>   to the sky; Higher than the stars of God I will set my throne. I will
>   sit in the mount of assembly, On the summit of Zaphon: I will mount
>   the back of a cloud— I will match the Most High.”

None of these mentions Lucifer.