# What is the major scholarship on the notion that Satan is the Serpent from The Fall?

Tags: genesis-bereishith, satan

Now, I do not believe that the Serpent is Satan. I can't find a particularly useful way of making that case.

But, despite the lack of anything concrete, the general public consensus has made the connection and effectively just states outright that "Satan is the Serpent." Is there any biblical reason to actually suspect this? Is there any real indication?

What did the ancient scholars think as a general consensus (there's always fringe groups)? What do modern scholars think as a general consensus?

Preferably with citations or references (I'll look into them myself, you don't have to actually post links). But if not, I'm still interested in hearing about it.

Comment: BTW "Lucifer" is an entirely Christian concept. Doesn't belong here. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99652/21

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Presenting a non-Jewish concept and then asking a question regarding the Jewish position on the matter is a question of [comparative religion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/828/comparative-religion-questions), which we don't allow on this Stack Exchange site. I edited out the term 'Lucifer' to make the question suitable for the site.